# How to get clipboard as input file name to Vim on bash?

Tags: bash, vim, clipboard, xclip, xsel

I install `xclip` to access system clipboard, my setting and some operations as below:

```
➜  ~ cat .zshrc | grep xclip
alias c="xclip -selection c"
alias v="xclip -selection c -o"
➜  ~ which dict | c
➜  ~ v       
/usr/bin/dict
➜  ~ sudo vim ??
```

`/usr/bin/dict` is a python script. And what I want to know is what can substitute `??` on my last command can use vim open file `/usr/bin/dict`?

Comment: Do you want `vim` to open the file named in the clipboard, or do you want `vim` to open with the contents of the clipboard in the editing buffer?

Comment: @wurtel the first, I want `vim` to open the file named in the clipboard! But the second is also a thing I don't know I will search it, if I don't find out it will be a new question to be asked.

Comment: @wurtel Is there a way to directly open with the contents of the clipboard in the editing buffer? In my mind, I have to run vim and then use `"+p` to paste it to vim. If there is a method, I could ask a new question at `Vim Stack Exchange`.

Comment: You can run `some-command | vim -` and vim will read its input and place that in the buffer.

Comment: @wurtel thanks a lot, `grep` and `-` cool, will check the function of `-`. Cool!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your current setup

```
sudo vim "$(v)"
```

will use [command substitution](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_03) to run your alias `v` and insert its output into the command line to be run before executing it, so it would run `sudo vim /usr/bin/dict` in the end. The quotes make sure it comes out as a single argument, and `$(...)` handles running the command and capturing its output.

This will only work from your interactive shell, since aliases aren't used elsewhere. If you want to access it from a script, you could make a small script somewhere in your `PATH` variable with the same command inside it.

---

You've tagged this [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) but then shown an extract from `.zshrc`, so note also that zsh has "[global aliases](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Grammar.html#Aliasing)" that expand anywhere:

```
alias -g v='"$(xclip -selection c -o)"'
```

and then just run `sudo vim v` and have that happen for free. Global aliases are almost always more trouble than they're worth, so I don't recommend that, but depending on your usage patterns *some* global alias might be convenient (I'd recommend a longer and more unusual name if you do: putting some odd punctuation in can help avoid running it by mistake, so `alias -g v# ...` or `@v` or `^v` or something).

Comment: Wow, thanks, global seems very convenient for me.  And the reason I use `zsh` but tagged `bash` is I think what works in zsh should be worked in bash, so I want a more general method.